# Can someone make this question clear to me and give me a hint?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, divergent-series

By using induction, prove that $s_{2^n} \geq 1 +n/2$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, where $s_j=\sum\limits_{i=1}^j 1/i$ is the $j$-th partial sum of the Harmonic Series. Note that this implies the partial sums diverge, which proves that the Harmonic Series diverges.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you do the base case?  Can you write out the induction assumption and what you need to prove from it?

Comment: Actually, it should be $s_{2^n}$ instead of $s_2^n$ (my fault, sorry). That's too few character for me to edit it again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and ross i do know how to deal with an induction question but this question was vague as into what im really trying to prove

Comment: You are trying to prove that the $2^n$th partial sum is greater than $1+n/2$.  You can do that by rounding all the terms from $2^k+1$ to $2^{k+1}$ down to $1/{2^{k+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $i=2^n, 2^n+1, \ldots, 2^{n+1}-1$, you have:

$$\frac{1}{i}>\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\quad 2^n\leq i<2^{n+1}$$

This will prove the fact that $\sum_1^\infty 1/n = \infty$, because $\sum_1^\infty 1/n = \lim_{n\to\infty} s_n$, and we will have:

$$s_1 = \frac11 = 1$$
$$s_2 = \frac11 + \frac12 = 1 + \frac12$$
$$s_4 = \frac11 + \cdots + \frac14 \geq 1 + 2/2$$
$$s_8 = \frac11 + \cdots + \frac18 \geq 1 + 3/2$$
$$s_{16} = \frac11 + \cdots + \frac1{16} \geq 1 + 4/2$$

So that the sequence $s_n$ will grow arbitrarily large (although slowly)